# Model crashes in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

All I added was a few sliders, and now my model seems to be crashing for now reason after 10 simulated days.  I am not using any animations or visual representations of my agents.

```
Error while drawing animation frame.
Possibly caused by dynamic properties of animation shapes.
The picture will be restored when (and if) the error goes away.
Error during model destruction:

NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException

    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeEmbeddedObjectIcon.resetSVGState(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeGroup.resetSVGState(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.Shape.removeSVGImage(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.SVGFrameProducer.n(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost.n(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost.setPresentable(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost.onAgentDestroyed_xjal(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.onDestroy(Unknown Source)

    at ae.Main.onDestroy(Main.java:3535)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.n(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.stop(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.stop(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost.executeCommand(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.e.onCommand(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.executor.basic.rest.BasicAnimationSessionController.lambda$null$9(BasicAnimationSessionController.java:112)

    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.i.acceptToAnimationSvgSession(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.executor.basic.rest.BasicAnimationSessionController.lambda$startController$10(BasicAnimationSessionController.java:112)

    at spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1.handle(ResponseTransformerRouteImpl.java:47)

    at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)

    at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:130)

    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.config.ALServerFactory$1.lambda$0(Unknown Source)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.QoSFilter.doFilter(QoSFilter.java:201)

    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.config.ALServerFactory$1.doHandle(Unknown Source)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1568)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Error during drawing animation frame:

java.lang.NullPointerException

    at com.anylogic.engine.FlowchartMappedPort.count(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Queue.a(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Queue.a(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Queue$3.updateDynamicProperties(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.Shape.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeGroup.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeGroup.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeGroup.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeEmbeddedObjectIcon.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeGroup.updateDynamicPropertiesStructural(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Presentable.n(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Presentable.updateShapeDynamicProperties(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.SVGFrameProducer.n(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost$1.l(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost$1.n(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.SVGFrameCollector.l(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.SVGFrameCollector.c(Unknown Source)

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Well, first take back your changes to really find out what exactly caused it.  The error message points to some visual elements... but impossible to say without you going full Sherlock first ;)

Comment: I started again, no matter what recent elements I removed it kept failing.  Not a great start for my evaluation of the product.

Comment: So I recreated the model, it runs until day 250 every time then crashes with the same error.  I am not animating anything, my agents have no visual presentation.